# Should I install these packages for python3?

Tags: package-management, python, python3

I'm learning python3 now and I want to ask a question about it.

My Ubuntu has Python2 and Python3 already. I'm just learning python3. Should I install these packages?

**Packages:**

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev zlib1g-dev ncurses-dev libreadline-dev libdb-dev libgdbm-dev libzip-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev
```

My Python3 version:

```
Python 3.4.3+
```

My Python2 version:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

Comment: For learning purposes? I would only install them if you specifically have a reason for it. `Idle` and `Idle3` are handy IDE's though.

Comment: Yes, for only learning the python3. But I don't know that which package is necessary for which code..

Comment: You will find out if you get import errors :), but most of the things you mention, I don't have on my system.

Comment: Ah okay! This comment helped enough with your answer. I will select now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For learning purposes, you need nothing more than python and a plain text editor like gedit. Indeed `python` (2) and `python3` are pre-installed on a modern Ubuntu version.

Additional libraries, I would only install if you have a specific reason for it. You will find out if you get import errors for example.
Many of the things you mention, I do not have on my system.

#### Idle, the python IDE

For automatic indentation, easy editing and test- running your code, I would advice to install both `idle` and `idle3` though (`python` IDE)

Comment: @InterestingKnox you're welcome!